# Checking NULLS in an OPTIONAL MATCH

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a cypher query like this:

```
MATCH (start:StartLabel)
OPTIONAL MATCH (start)-[:A]->(end1:EndLabel)
OPTIONAL MATCH (start)-[:B|C]->(middle:MiddleLabel)-[:D]->(end2:EndLabel)
WHERE NOT(end1 IS NULL AND end2 IS NULL)
RETURN *
```

In this graph model there are multiple valid ways to reach `(end)` from `(start)` but I want to make sure that the result matches at least one of the possible `OPTIONAL MATCH` paths. For some reason I continue to get results where both `end1` and `end2` are `NULL` with this `WHERE` clause. Am I missing something about how Cypher processes `OPTIONAL MATCH` and `WHERE` together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternate way to get the results:

```
MATCH (start:StartLabel)-[:A]->(end:EndLabel)
RETURN start, NULL as middle, end
UNION
MATCH (start:StartLabel)-[:B|C]->(middle:MiddleLabel)-[:D]->(end:EndLabel)
RETURN start, middle, end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been told that `WHERES` always apply to the most previous `(OPTIONAL )MATCH`, so perhaps this will work?

```
MATCH (start:StartLabel)
OPTIONAL MATCH
  (start)-[:A]->(end1:EndLabel),
  (start)-[:B|C]->(middle:MiddleLabel)-[:D]->(end2:EndLabel)
WHERE NOT(end1 IS NULL AND end2 IS NULL)
RETURN *
```

As as aside, I feel like `end1 IS NOT NULL OR end2 IS NOT NULL` reads better to me

Comment: Interesting. I set up some unit tests and it would appear that `WHERE` actually applies only to the first `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause. I couldn't ever get this to work with any combination of `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses or a single `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause with multiple patterns.